# Postgresql: Merge multiple geometries into single geometry using Join

Tags: sql, postgresql, geometry

Say I have two tables, `geom_levels` and `taz_geoms` where `taz_geoms` has the columns as follows:

**taz_geoms**

```
id(int)   state(int)   county(int)  taz(int)  geom(geometry(MultiPolygon,4326))
```

and geom_levels looks like this:

**geom_levels**

```
TAZ         COUNTY  STATE   DISTRICT
1           1       29      1
2           1       29      1
3           1       29      1
4           2       29      2
5           2       29      2
6           2       29      2
7           2       29      3
8           3       29      3
9           3       29      3
10          3       29      4
11          3       29      4
12          3       29      4
13          4       29      5
14          4       29      5
15          4       29      5
16          4       29      6
17          4       29      6
```

How would I go about combining these taz geometries into county, state, and district geometries? I would like to have a `county_geoms`, `state_geoms`, and `district_geoms` table. I have see that you can use [`ST_UNION`](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_Union.html) with a geom array, but how would I generate such an array for counties or districts?

I was thinking something like this for counties:

```
SELECT ST_UNION(SELECT geom from taz_geoms GROUP BY county);
```

and for districts:

```
SELECT ST_UNION(SELECT geom from taz_geoms t LEFT JOIN geom_levels gl ON gl.taz = t.taz GROUP BY district);
```

But those options do not see possible.

Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

try with:

SELECT ST_UNION( **ARRAY**( 'YOUR SELECT geoms QUERY' ) );

in your case:

SELECT ST_UNION(ARRAY( (SELECT geom from taz_geoms t LEFT JOIN geom_levels gl ON gl.taz = t.taz GROUP BY district) ));

I had the same problem and got it to work with postgre usin the ARRAY() function ;)